# TouchesBegan method not selecting right nodes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, sknode

In my TouchesBegan method of SKScene I am checking if the user has selected a node as so:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
NSLog(@"node.name: %@",node.name);

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"1"]){
    bgColor = 1;
}
else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"2"]){
    bgColor = 2;
}
else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"3"]){
    bgColor = 3;
}
else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"4"]){
    bgColor = 4;
}
else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"5"]){
    bgColor = 5;
}
else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"6"]){
    bgColor = 6;
}
```

My nodes are all initialized in method like so:

```
SKShapeNode *bg = [SKShapeNode node];
[bg setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(self.size.width-50*2, 55, 50, 50), 6, 6, nil)];
bg.fillColor = [SKColor orangeColor];
bg.glowWidth = 0;
bg.name = @"6";
return bg;
```

The methods are all similar, except for the name and color properties, of course.
The nodes are divided in two lines, one at y 120 and the other at y 55, the Xs are different, but when the user clicks any node in the line 120 or 55 the node name logged is the one from the node at the most right.
Why is that happening? And what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could recreate you problem and found the solution:

Don't position the `SKShapeNode` by setting the start and end point in `CGRectMake()`. Instead, just use the regular `postion` property of the `SKShapeNode`. Otherwise, the nodes seem to overlap each other, although the shapes are at different coordinates.

```
SKShapeNode *bg = [SKShapeNode node];
[bg setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), 6, 6, nil)];
bg.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width-50*2, 55);
bg.fillColor = [SKColor orangeColor];
bg.glowWidth = 0;
bg.name = @"6";
return bg;
```